# Adding list to mysql database

Tags: python, mysql-python

This has been driving me crazy for two days. I am trying to add a 2d list to a mysql database. My code is as follows:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb

i = 0
ins = open( "test.txt", "r" )
skeds = []
for line in ins:
  i = i + 1
  line = line.replace(",", "")
  #line = line.replace('""', "")
  line = line.replace("\xc2\xa0", "EMPTY")
  line = line.replace("\xef\xbb\xbf", "")
  line = line.strip()
  line = line.strip().upper()
  line = line.split('""')
  line = filter(None, line)
  skeds.append(line)

del skeds[i-1]
print(skeds[277])

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'test123', 'sked')

with con:
#AT this point sked = ['WATCH', 'VT-X', 'EMPTY', '10:30', '15:00', 'EMPTY', 'DOE JON [1XX]', 'PM SDO', '4.5', 'EMPTY', 'EMPTY']
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test3")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test3(Type VARCHAR(50), VT VARCHAR(50), Brief VARCHAR(50), EDT VARCHAR(50), RTB VARCHAR(50), Instructor VARCHAR(50), Student VARCHAR(50), Event VARCHAR(50), Hrs VARCHAR(50), Remarks VARCHAR(75), Location VARCHAR(50))")


params = "INSERT INTO test3(Type, VT, Brief, EDT, RTB, Instructor, Student, Event, Hrs, Remarks, Location) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
dats = skeds[36]

cur.executemany(params, dats)
```

Below is what I get for an error:

```
smartsked Main$ python sked1.py
['WATCH', 'VT-9', 'EMPTY', '10:30', '15:00', 'EMPTY', 'SENG PATRICK [1STLT]', 'PM SDO', '4.5', 'EMPTY', 'EMPTY']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sked1.py", line 36, in <module>
    cur.executemany(params, dats)   
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 244, in executemany
    self.errorhandler(self, ProgrammingError, msg.args[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Any suggestions? I would also like to iterate the executemany function over the length of my skeds list in order to have the full 2d list placed into the database.

Comment: You've printed skeds[277], but you're trying to insert skeds[36]. What does that contain?

Comment: Are you sure you pasted with proper indent? Cause `skeds.append(line)` is only going to append one line, which you promptly delete, and the next line will error. So I'm guessing no?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Both skeds[277] and skeds[36] contain the same amount of information just different strings. You can see the printout for skeds[277] in the error printout. [36] is the same with different strings.

Comment: @WayneWerner - Good catch, I did enter the here incorrectly. skeds.append(line) is indented. del skeds[i-1]  is to delete the last line which was nonsense data. By deleting the last line it gave me a perfect i x 11 list of lists.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have discovered that the code works perfectly if I use cur.execute(params, dats) but fails with cur.executemany(params, dats). Suggestions? I still have a little hair I haven't torn out yet... wouldnt' mind keeping it

Answer (score 0):

Data formatting was the issue. My list inadvertently had 2x the data as was expected.